# Webservice sourced images show as ? in certain versions of stock Android Browser

Tags: c#, javascript, android, html, .net

I am attempting to dynamically source images, using an ID rendered into the path when the page binds it data. However, the images are showing as blue question marks in a box [?]. The images load fine on iOS, Mobile Chrome, older versions of Android browser (2.3), newer versions of Android browser (4.2.2) and IE/Firefox/Chrome on desktop. This issue appears (so far) only on Android 4.0 and 4.1.

This is how i'm trying to load the images:

Ex. `<img src="../services/getImage?id=f6c799b2-ff31-4fbc-abc9-31f20d5e69c8">`

This request hits a .NET webservice (IHttpAsyncHandler implementation) which looks like this

> ```
>     public  virtual UploadedImage   getImage(Guid imageId) {
>         string              eTag;
>         Entities.Image.DTO  image   = null;
>         if
>         (
>             image = //get image entity
>         )
>         {
>             eTag    =  Delta.Crypto.CreateMD5Hash(image.ModifiedDate.ToEpoch().ToString());
>             if (Request.Headers[HTTPRequestHeaderKeys.IfNoneMatch].IsNotNullOrEmpty() && Request.Headers[HTTPRequestHeaderKeys.IfNoneMatch] == eTag)
>             {
>                 this.RespondWithNoUpdate(); 
>                 return null;
>             }
>             if (image.ImageUrl.IsNullOrEmpty() || image.ImageContent == null || image.ImageContent.Length == 0)
>             {
>                 this.RespondWithNotFound();
>                 return null;
>             }
>             Response.AddHeader(HTTPResponseHeaderKeys.ETag, eTag);
>             return new UploadedImage()
>             {
>                 contentType     = "image/" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(image.ImageUrl).ToLower().Substring(1),
>                 fileContents    = image.ImageContent,
>                 fileName        = image.ImageUrl
>             };
>         }
>         return  null;
> ```

So we're setting the mime type using the file extensions, which is maybe not 100% reliable, but i have confirmed to be correct in these cases.

Here is a copy of the Request and successful Response on my desktop Chrome browser
Request:
`Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive 
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/delta/events/bigevent/app/event.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36`

Response:

`Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="2dab739b-a06c-4579-8555-0598d738f858_eventApplayoutContainerEventApplicationlandingScreenImageContainer_background-image.png"
Content-Length:236
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Tue, 11 Feb 2014 19:53:31 GMT
ETag:1c79507d4969ea7534f3068ca1e60be4
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache`

My only guess is that when requesting an image in this way, the img control does not know the mime type when rendered, and thus is complaining.

Note: The request does succeed on the Android browser when accessing directly (in a separate tab).

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing the [?] and a potential solution? I haven't been able to locate much, if any documentation on the stock browser. If you have a link to some documentation, that would also be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I should note that resource images with relative paths are loading fine

`Ex. <img src="../images/EmptyProfile.png">`

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to figure this one out.

The root of the issue is that the Android browser on those versions **does not** send an Accept header with the request.

My webservice tries to negotiate a content delivery type based upon the client preferences. There was no default.

Hope this helps someone in the future!